# How can I get rid of the Falmer tome misc objective?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I've found Unknown Book, Vol. 1 and sold it to Urag, but the objective 'Bring Ancient Falmer Tome to Urag-gro Shub' is still active. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you play on PC I'd try the console command: `setstage DLC1VQFVBooks <stage>` where `<stage>` is either 0, 10, 15, 170, 200, 250 or 255. I cannot tell you which one, but I can tell you that 0 would set the quest as 'not interacted with yet' and 10 is the stage where you are asked to bring the book.

So 0 should remove the quest from the log but would re-enable you to do the quest. Therefore I recommend trying maybe even 100, which used to be the standard `quest completed` stage.

EDIT: Setting the quest's stage to 200 worked for kotekzot. This has been done with the console command: `setstage DLC1VQFVBooks 200`

Comment: setstage 200 did it for me, thanks!

Comment: @kotekzot Great! :D I'll Add it to the answer :)

Comment: Delivering all 4 books in 1 go (another playthrough) marked the objective as complete. Possibly the intended behavior.